# error running robot script from Github Actions using connected app

Tags: connected-apps, cumulusci, github-actions

I followed [this article](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/headless.html) (JWT Flow Authorization) but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error retrieving access token:
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved this
consumer"}
```

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
cci task run robot \
 --org myOrgName \
 --vars BROWSER:headlesschrome \
 --suites ./mytestsuite.robot
```

Does anybody know what I might be missing?

Highlights:

1. I have the variable `CUMULUSCI_ORG_myOrgName` defined;
2. The connected app is already being used by the sfdx cli;
3. I have added the full scope to the connected app;
4. The SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL is defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant authorization once :

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i <connected app client_id> -f <pathname to private key file> -o <username>
```